# Complex select statement in oracle

Tags: .net, oracle, c#-4.0

I have a table that holds Client_ID and Communication_Date I would like to produce below table. Table should list previous and last communication dates.Is there any way to write a query for it? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

```
ORIGINAL TABLE

ID    Client_ID     Communication_date
1     1001          01-05-2013
2     1002          01-05-2013
3     1003          02-05-2013
4     1001          09-05-2013
5     1001          14-05-2013
6     1002          18-05-2013
7     1002          25-05-2013



Requested Table
Client_ID           PreviousCom_Date       LastCom_date
1001                01-05-2013             09-05-2013
1001                09-05-2013             14-05-2013
1002                01-05-2013             18-05-2013
1002                18-05-2013             25-05-2013
1003                02-05-2013             Null or whatever
```

Comment: Can you define precisely what you mean by "PreviousCom_Date"?  Is it just the next-to-last Communication_Date?

Comment: are you just doing a group by with the max comdate?  If so, what do you mean by previous com date?

Comment: I would like to flag first date in table as Previous communication date and the second date as Last Communication date. If I choose the date range for example between 01-05-2013 and 30-05-2013 I would like to list like requested table.

Comment: `select client_id, min(com_date) as first_com, max(com_date) as last_com from foobar where com_date < ? and com_date > ? group by client_id`

Comment: Not actually, as you will see from second table on next communication, last communication date is becoming first communication date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The analytical [`LAG`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions075.htm) function will pair up the dates for you. This will pair up the current/previous dates:

```
SELECT
  Client_ID,
  Communication_Date AS PreviousCom_Date,
  LAG(Communication_Date) OVER (
    PARTITION BY Client_ID
    ORDER BY Communication_Date DESC) AS LastCom_Date
FROM PrevTable;
```

Then there's the problem of making sure only rows with "Previous" and "Last" values are included, *unless* like Client_ID 1003 there's only one row in the source table. That can be taken care of by counting the `Client_ID` rows and checking for (a) only one row for the client or (b) if more than one row for the client then both dates must have values:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    Client_ID,
    Communication_Date AS PreviousCom_Date,
    LAG(Communication_Date) OVER (
      PARTITION BY Client_ID
      ORDER BY Communication_Date DESC) AS LastCom_Date,
    COUNT(*) OVER (
      PARTITION BY Client_ID) AS DatePair_Count
  FROM PrevTable
  )
WHERE DatePair_Count = 1
   OR (PreviousCom_Date IS NOT NULL AND LastCom_Date IS NOT NULL)
```

Just precede the above query with `CREATE TABLE whatever AS` and it will create the new table.

There's a SQL Fiddle of the `SELECT` statement [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/694bb/1).

Comment: Thank you so much Ed. I am really appreciated for your help. All the best. :))))

Comment: You're welcome Hakan - glad it worked for you, and great question!